# Geocode Shape not working on H.service.Platform#getSearchService

Tags: reactjs, here-api, heremaps

Currently on my app I am using
`H.service.GeocodingService`
to retrieve using geocode() method the shape of a location, for it I was passing the options:

```
 searchText: `${zip}+DEU`,
      additionalData: `IncludeShapeLevel,postalCode`,
```

however as indicated on their documentation this is deprecated and not actively developed, they suggest we use instead:
`H.service.SearchService`
however seems that the shape is not returned from that service, and couldnt find any further details about how to retrieve the shape.

furthermore, if I not include the q: attribute on the parameters it throws an error, meaning that the searchText: is not the source of truth anymore?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in this topic and with the same problem, after digging all the way down through the rabbit hole I stumbled upon this table,

[table](https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/geocoding-and-search-api-migration-guide/page/migration-geocoder/topics-api/geocoding.html#currently-not-supported)

as of today this funtionality is not yet available from heremaps itself.